# Paliate key sending wrong keycodes

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard, keyboard-layout

After a waterspill over my laptop's keyboard the left arrow and the up arrow send grabled keycodes which correspond to several other keys.

I can live without those keys since I can remap other keys to replace them. Now I'm looking how could I disable them so that I don't accidentally press them and send who knows what.

I've checked with `xev` and `evtest` and the keys send several keycodes, pressing it shortly sends the same keycodes but pressing without releasing can send whatever.

Any ideas on how to handle this, if any?